# Slow MySQL-Query due to joins

Tags: php, mysql

In a project, I detect a slow query. Sometimes it lasts more than 30 seconds. Most likely, it's slow due to its joins. It's a website for learning a website and the query shows the results of learning vocabulary list.
Firstly, I have to request the user's vocabulary list. Subsequently I asked for the terms which are part of the list and finally, I have to find out the results for these terms.

```
lists: 
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ul_id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ul_user  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
|  […]               
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
Index on ul_user

key table lists/vocs
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| rlv_list | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| rlv_voc  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
Indices both columns

results:
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| rv_user     | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| rv_voc      | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| rv_result   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
|   […]
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
Index on rv_user and rv_voc
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS total, 
        SUM(rv_result = 1) AS correct, 
        SUM(rv_result = 2) AS incorrect
FROM user_lists
LEFT JOIN rel_lists_vocs ON rlv_list =  ul_id
LEFT JOIN results_vocabulary ON rv_voc =  rlv_voc
WHERE ul_user = :user AND rv_user = :user
GROUP BY ul_id
```

How can I make this query faster? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Explain results:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type | possible_keys                 | key          | key_len | ref                                   | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | lists         | ref  | PRIMARY,ul_user               | ul_user      | 4       | const                                 |   18 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | lists_vocs     | ref  | noduplicates,rlv_list,rlv_voc | noduplicates | 4       | xx.ul_id       |   14 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | results | ref  | rv_user,rv_voc                | rv_voc       | 5       | xx.rlv_voc |   67 | Using where                                           |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Start by doing an EXPLAIN on this code, then look for any missing indexes

Comment: I added the EXPLAIN result to my question

Comment: what kinds of row numbers are we looking at. What is the noduplicates table?

Comment: noduplicate is a unique-key about two columns in order to avoid duplicates.

Comment: How many rows in the tables/query?

Comment: @BadHorsie 941 lists, 32,389 list-term-relationships, 847,964 results.